# How do I search for multiple key words that appear PDF's, from a directory of pdf files (approx 5000 pdfs)

Tags: python, pdf, keyword, scrape

I am relatively new to python, but have decided to try biuld a tool for work which will look through a subsection of our PDF documents for certain ketwords, input by the user.

So far I have this working well for 1 keyword at a time, and I have managed to upgrade the GUI. However, I cannot manage to search for more than 1 keyword/phrase within the document. For example, I want to search a name so I can input that and it works fine, it birngs me back all PDF's where this name appears (which is great). But when I try add another search term/phrase I cannot get this to work.

For example if I want to search for all the Mr Smith's in the system and then the name of a medication ( Iw work in toxicology). I want to input: Smith, paracetamol
But this does not work.

It only works for Mr Smith in isolation. I think this is because it is using exact text, but I have no idea how to add more key words.

Any help is appreciated, I have posted my code so far which includes all the GUI stuff

```
import requests,webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import *
import os
import fitz
import os
import customtkinter

path= r'O:\Sent Questions'
files = os.listdir(path)

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("700x350") 
root.title("Questions Keyword Search")

label=customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text="Questions Keyword Search Engine",font=("Inter",30))
label.pack(side=TOP) 
text=StringVar()
def search():
    global entry
    Search = entry.get()
    print(Search)
    for file in files:
        doc=fitz.open(path+'\\'+file)
        for page in doc:
            text = page.get_text()
            # print(text)
            result = text.find(Search)
            if result != -1:
                print(file)
                pass

            #need to add another loop the key words for, so for each page in dock again search for more keywords
            
label_1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text="Enter Keywords Below",font=("Inter",15))
label_1.place(x=275,y=100)

label_2=customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text="You can input as many as you'd like but they must be in double quotation marks and split by commas",font=("Inter",12))
label_2.place(x=97,y=130)

label_3=customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text='Example: cocaine, SoHT, LC-MS',font=("Inter",12))
label_3.place(x=250,y=150)

entry=customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=root,width=200)
entry.place(x=252,y=190)
button=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root,text="Search",command=search)
button.place(x=285,y=230)
root.mainloop()

input("prompt: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to select pages where ***all*** keywords are mentioned, that the user entered.

I would request the user to separate keywords by commas and do not enforce double " apostrophes as separators. Then split the user input by comma to get a list of user keywords. To avoid upper-lower case issues, translate everything to lower: the keywords and the extracted text. Your selection would then look something like this:

```py
def search():
    global entry
    Search = entry.get()
    kw_list = Search.lower().split(",")

    for file in files:
        doc=fitz.open(path+'\\'+file)
        for page in doc:
            text = page.get_text().lower()
            for kw in kw_list:
                if kw not in text:  # skip page for any missing keyword
                    continue
            # all keywords occurs on this page!
            print(f"found on page {page.number+1} of file {doc.name}")
```

Not sure if the selection logic meets your requirements. Maybe you want to be less strict and accept a page already if at least n-1 keywords are there or something. So you would need to change the selection and cound the matches before you ignore a page.

Comment: Hi, this helped :) I understand where you're coming from and this works for each keyword, but I get some many duplicates (assuming repeats in the PDFs - they are very long and pretty repetitive). However I need it to just give me the file name if there is at least one instance of each keyword in the files. But the file needs to contain both keywords, not just one of them. Is this something that can be easily done?

Comment: Someone just mentioned I made an error with handling the loop with the `continue`: the intention was skipping the page, and I wouldn't achieve this in this way. Sorry. So let me try again to understand you: The file is eligible if and only if all of the keywords occur (on any page). right? If so, I would suggest using Python sets as follows.

Comment: Yes that is correct, thanks.  I'll try that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```py
def search():
    global entry
    Search = entry.get()
    keywords = set(Search.lower().split(","))  # make a set of desired keywords

    for file in files:
        doc=fitz.open(path+'\\'+file)
        file_keywords = set()
        for page in doc:
            text = page.get_text().lower()
            for kw in kw_list:
                if kw in text:
                    file_keywords.add(kw)  # take note this keyword occurred
        # check whether all desired keywords are present in this file
        if keywords <= file_keywords:
            print(f"All keywords in file '{doc.name}'.")
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this and with a couple of tweaks to get it running I arent sure its working as intended, since I am getting many positive searches for when searching for very specific terms, like it isn't confirming that all words in the list are present.

Comment: The logic above gives a positive if all keywords are a substring on at least one page. It does **not** ensure that the keyword is an isolated word in the text. So it will accept "123sohtxyz" for having found "SoHT". This may be too forgiving in your situation. You may want to first split the page text in a list of words, and then check if a kw is one of the words.Maybe like this `text = page.get_text().lower().replace("\n", " ")` remove the newlines. Then `words = text.split()` and check for `if kw in words: ...`.

Comment: On the other hand, the previous idea will not accept "cocaine," as an occurrence of "cocaine". So some more massaging may be required. There is another text extraction variant, which extracts the words on a page - together with position info, which we don't need here: `words = [w[4].lower() for w page.get_text("words")]`. This will deliver the word strings without punctuations.

Comment: Excellent, I think I have this working now :) Thanks for all your help, with the 2 quick tests I've done it has worked accordingly.